# Would tying Jeannie's arms behind her back render her powerless in I Dream of Jeannie?

Tags: i-dream-of-jeannie

Typically Jeannie is shown crossing her arms and nodding to perform her magic. Is this a needed action? Or are there examples where Jeannie performs magic without the gesture?

Comment: This question reminds me of how Wonder Woman would lose her powers if she were tied up.

Comment: I wonder if this would also be the case if you prevented Samantha from Bewitched from moving her nose...

Comment: I have a feeling this may be a throwback to "Bewitched" convention - you need to **show** you do magick

Comment: The true requirement is that little soundclip they play when she blinks. Without that, nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's already confirmed that Jeannie can do her magic without crossing her arms, but apparently she does need to blink.  From the season five episode ["The Blood of a Jeannie"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_I_Dream_of_Jeannie_episodes):

> As genies have red and green blood, Roger masquerades his arm as Jeannie's so that she can get a certificate of perfect health to be eligible to marry Tony. A man at the jeweler's store steals Tony's wallet so Jeannie blinks the jeweler's store into his office. Roger stops anyone leaving as they will walk out into a NASA corridor. **Jeannie's eyes have been dilated and she can't blink but when she can she makes the thief return the wallet and blinks the store back.** Roger apologizes and leaves when a man walks in from the street.

Answer (score 5):

No.  As you can see in this [video clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9mY8NMQtGA#t=0m25s), Jeannie can perform magic without crossing her arms.